# Is there any way to avoid smart labels duplicating existing labels?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I see there were some updates to [Gmail smart labels](http://lifehacker.com/gmails-new-smart-labels-auto-categorize-purchases-tra-1513344490) where they now auto categorize items as purchases, travel, etc.  I already have a label called travel and it seems like it treats these as two different labels (even though they have the same name).  Is there anyway to:

1. remove "travel" as a smart label?
2. Have it use my "travel" label to avoid duplicate labels on my emails?
3. Any other way to remove this duplication?

Comment: there used to be an option to skip marking it with smart labels when configuring filters, that option seems to have been removed now